# possible to show 2 different colors in one geom_density plot?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, formatting

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, 0, 1), y = rnorm(1000,0, 2), z = rnorm(1000, 2, 1.5))
df.m <- melt(df)

ggplot(df.m) +
    geom_density(aes(x=value, y=..density..)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=1, linetype="dotted")
```

Possible to make the left of vertical line in one color and right side another color?

Comment: The easiest way will probably be to pre-calculate the density outside of ggplot and then plot the raw points using `geom_line` and color it using your own grouping variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going through the same issue, so I put out this alternative, which may not be the best way, but it is easy to understand and works very well.

Using package dplyr (to create the example data frame) and ggplot (to build the plot).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Data example:

```
df <- tibble(x = rnorm(1000))
```

The first step is to create a **temporary density plot**, so we can access it's build to extract informations of the plot (in our scenario, we are trying to access the x and y values of the plot):

```
temporary_plot <- df %>%  
 ggplot() +
 geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

Once we got our temporary plot, we are using the function **ggplot2::ggplot_build()** to access the plot's build:

```
build <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(temporary_plot)
```

Inside the build of a plot, there is the data used to contruct it, so we reach this data to define the classes to be delimited, in this example, we are setting x <= 0 or x > 0 (it could have more than 2 classes):

```
df_breaks <- build$data[[1]] %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(x <= 0 ~ 'class1', # Arbitrary value, just as an example
                            TRUE ~ 'class2'))
```

The last step is to build a new plot, but this time using the **ggplot2::geom_area()** function:

```
df_breaks %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(aes(x = x,
                y = y,
                fill = status))
```

I cannot attach the final plot because of my reputation, I am new in stack overflow, but I hope this answers your question.

This is the complete code with no interruptions:

```
library(gpglot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = rnorm(1000))

temporary_plot <- df %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  geom_density(
    aes(x = x)
  )

build <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(temporary_plot)

df_breaks <- build$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(status = case_when(x <= 0 ~ 'class1', # Arbitrary value, just as an example
                            TRUE ~ 'class2'))

df_breaks %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(
    aes(x = x,
        y = y,
        fill = status)
  )
```

And this is the plot:
[image]

Comment: Great to see an 8+ year-old question get an answer. There probably is a more succinct way to do this, but you are correct, it is easy to follow.

Comment: Also, in case the OP wanted to maintain the line plot, simply change `geom_area(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = status)) +` to `geom_area(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = status), fill = NA) +`